# Prayers and blessings in times of the Beis Hamikdosh and earlier?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, shacharis-morning-prayer

Were there morning Berachot? Berachot on foods?

Did people go to shul every day in the times of the Beis Hamikdosh, or only on Monday and Thursday to hear the Torah reading? (I'm guessing perhaps not every day as they were farmers and didn't have much time if they were working the field.)

What did they say when wearing tefillin? When did praying with a Minyan start?

Interested specifically about customs  that were in the days of the Beis Hamikdash and earlier but **not** things that were done  **in the Beis Hamikdash itself**, i.e. what the kohanim did while performing their duties.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86754/15256

Comment: @Kazibácsi saw that question before posting this question. It is related, but different.

Comment: That's why I wrote related and not duplicate. Such links make browsing the questions easier.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29575/did-the-kohanim-wear-tefillin-during-their-temple-services

Comment: From mishnayot in the 4th chapter of Taanit we see that there were synagogues. And that there was additional contents at the time of maamad. We can infer that in standard days the tefila was different but existent

Comment: What about davening that took place in the Beis HaMikdash that wasn’t a part of the regular service? Are you interested in that?

Comment: @DonielF perhaps, but the question is specifically about not in the beis Hamikdash

Comment: @kouty what's maamad?

Comment: Maamad was a kind of participation of Jewish not kohen or Levi regarding korbanot tsibur. See the 4th chapter of misnayot Taanit

Comment: I don't have all the sources off-hand, but most of the formalized _tefillah_ we have today comes from the _Anshei Knesses Hagdolah_, at the beginning of _Bayis Sheini_. The Mishnah in _Tamid_ specifically mentions the Kohanim reciting _Kriyas Shema_ with its _brachos._

Comment: @Menachem yes i did read that, that's why I was specifically asking for before that period.

Comment: @larry909 Perhaps you should have specified you meant during _Bayis Rishon_, or during the interregnum (during _Golus Bavel_). I can't answer, but I imagine laying _tefillin_ would have been like wearing _tzitzis_ today, worn all day with nothing in particular being said. You've seen _Rambam, Hilchos Tefilla_?

Comment: @Menachem everyone wore tefillin all day? Sages and rabbis or everyone? Hard to believe laypeople would be able to work all day with tefillin...